# cannot import name 'test' from 'unittest'

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, python-unittest

I create new virtualenv, import unittest in shell, try to import test from unittest, get an error
I need unittest.test for my project what should I do?

````
max24@LAPTOP-6RUMBKO8:~$ virtualenv test2
created virtual environment CPython3.8.10.final.0-64 in 196ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/max24/test2, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/max24/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.3.1, setuptools==58.3.0, wheel==0.37.0
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
max24@LAPTOP-6RUMBKO8:~$ source test2/bin/activate
(test2) max24@LAPTOP-6RUMBKO8:~$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import unittest
>>> from unittest import test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'test' from 'unittest' (/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/__init__.py)
>>>```
````

Comment: I am not using any tutorial, I am working with a project whose files have
```from unittest.test.support import LoggingResult```
and it throw ```No module named 'unittest.test```

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `unittest.test` certainly exists: https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/unittest/test since Python 2.7: https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/v2.7/Lib/unittest/test

Comment: @begletsoid Your stdlib seems to be broken. Please check if you can import `unittest.test` with Python 3.8 outside of virtual environments. If not — reinstall stdlib.

Comment: @phd Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I can't find a way to reinstall the standard libraries

Comment: ok, seems like the problem was that i ran poetry install outside of vurtualenv.